# Creating a database schema from The Movie Database

Tags: database, database-design

I'm trying to create a database schema using information pulled from the themoviedb api.

I thought I was doing ok until I went to add in the television series, then I got really confused.

The TMDb API seems to treat television series and movies as completely separate things. It further divides television listings into series, seasons, and episodes.

For example there is a separate cast listing for television seasons (season regulars) and individual episodes (guest cast). I have no idea how to reflect all this in the database.

I've tried my best to model everything below, but I think there's something wrong somewhere. Please ignore the datatypes.

[image: first attempt at a schema]

```
Role can be either writer, director, or actor.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RECme.jpg

Hi user2146821,

Your database design looks good, with the exception of how to display the relations between regular cast and guest cast members, as you've expressed.

Currently, you are approaching the scenario by having a singular join table between Movie, TV Seasons, TV Episodes and Person. This creates a table for which you cannot have either a singular primary key nor a correct composite primary key, as you will have nulls for any given record.

In the linked image above, you can see another way of handling this relationship - you create three join tables, each with Person on one side and a corresponding table on the other (either Movie, TV Season or TV Episode). This eliminates nulls from the join tables, allows for composite primary keys to be formed in the joins tables and structures the database in a more meaningful way.

Comment: Thank you very much. I find this sort of thing really confusing. You start with "every table should represent an object" and end up creating 5 extra tables just to represent "people do jobs in movies/tv."